# Задублировать строку при переименовании столбца DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, анализ

Всем добрый день столкнулся с проблемой

Есть датафрейм с перечнем марок:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mark': 'VAG VAG vag vag MB MB Hyuindai/Kia'.split(),
'item': [7575, 77777, 25775, 175757, 3355353, 3566, 56363636]})
```

Есть словарь для переименования марок в читаемый вид:

```
dict2={'VAG':'Volkswagen',
       'vag':'Volkswagen',
       'MB':'Mercedes-benz', 
       'Mercedes':'Mercedes-benz', 
       'Hyuindai/Kia':'Kia',
       'Hyuindai/Kia':'Hyuindai'}
```

далее переименовываю значения в столбце

```
df['mark'] = df['mark'].replace(dict1)
```

На выходе получаю

```
       mark      item
0     Volkswagen      7575
1     Volkswagen     77777
2     Volkswagen     25775
3     Volkswagen    175757
4  Mercedes-benz   3355353
5  Mercedes-benz      3566
6       Hyuindai  56363636
```

Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли как то сделать чтобы по ключу 'Hyuindai/Kia' добавлялась ещё одна строка с Kia?

Чтобы получилось примерно так

```
     mark      item
0     Volkswagen      7575
1     Volkswagen     77777
2     Volkswagen     25775
3     Volkswagen    175757
4  Mercedes-benz   3355353
5  Mercedes-benz      3566
6       Hyuindai  56363636
7            Kia  56363636
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы понимаете, что у вас неверный словарь для замены? в словаре не могут быть два элемента с одинаковыми ключами. Предлагаю сделать так:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'mark': 'VAG VAG vag vag MB MB Hyuindai/Kia'.split(),'item': [7575, 77777, 25775, 175757, 3355353, 3566, 56363636]})

dict3={'VAG':'Volkswagen',
       'vag':'Volkswagen',
       'MB':'Mercedes-benz', 
       'Mercedes':'Mercedes-benz', 
       'Hyuindai/Kia':['Kia', 'Hyuindai']}
df['mark'] = df['mark'].map(dict3).fillna(df['mark']) #обновлено
```

вы получите такой датафрейм:

```
              mark      item
0       Volkswagen      7575
1       Volkswagen     77777
2       Volkswagen     25775
3       Volkswagen    175757
4    Mercedes-benz   3355353
5    Mercedes-benz      3566
6  [Kia, Hyuindai]  56363636
```

а теперь просто:

```
res = df.explode('mark').reset_index(drop=True)
```

и получаете res:

```
            mark      item
0     Volkswagen      7575
1     Volkswagen     77777
2     Volkswagen     25775
3     Volkswagen    175757
4  Mercedes-benz   3355353
5  Mercedes-benz      3566
6            Kia  56363636
7       Hyuindai  56363636
```

Comment: Да конечно понимаю, что такого быть не может. Просто забыл удалить строку наверное сори. Ваш вариант работает, но появилась другая проблема. Строки, которые нужно оставить, которых нет в словаре, но есть в столбце заменились на NaN есть способ их сохранить?

Comment: я обновил ответ (смотрите строку с `map`)

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное очень помогли! Все работает.